# Execute some code only on my device

Tags: android

is it possible to run a code block(a method or something similiar) only on my device? it should be a piece of code that I can keep into the public apk but get executed only for me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please clarify—you want to, say, use some unique identifier for your device and conditionally run the code based on that unique identifier?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A simple example would be: when I click on the app it will show a toast message ONLY TO ME. Everyone else will not see that toast message. So, if we want to see it in a pseudo-code way it could be: if(me){Toast.make.....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Android device has a unique device ID. You can find out yours and put it in a conditional if block to display the toast.

Steps

1. Find your device Unique device ID and save it (or hard-code it in the code ).
2. if(device_unique_id == MY_DEVICE_ID)

   ```
   //show toast
   ```

More details on obtaining it are here [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution by using a device id, but not from that post which force you to put some restrictions on the apk.